# User/Pass Authentication PHP/MySQL - Comparison in PHP or MySQL Query?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

When authenticating a user with php and MySQL, which of the following is better practice?


**Method 1**

MySQL Select where username and password match.

If a result comes back, user is authenticated.


**Method 1**

MySQL Select password where username matches.

Use php to compare passwords for successful login.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first one usually, because no need to write extra code if you can do it within MySQL query, also, don't forget to make `username` column unique index.

Comment: That's what I was thinking, I just saw it done the other way, and it made me question the way I was doing it. Unless someone else provides information to the contrary, I will select your answer.